# Are you aware of any tools for osx that can show my daily weekly and monthly internet usage?

Tags: osx, network-monitor, internet, macbook

Currently i am on the go and i need to monitor my data usage from the my mac. 
Do you know any tools (preferebly free) that i can see my network usage so i wont exceed my quota ?
Thanks.

Comment: related (closed) question: https://superuser.com/q/123001/83300